# How to combine Masonry with Isotope w/ a fully responsive solution + filtering and searching

Tags: search, filter, responsive, masonry, jquery-isotope

I've created the code below:

http://codepen.io/dkpen/pen/dppoKj?editors=0110

this is fully responsive; and it was a workaround solution to get Isotope filtering working with my actual Masonry solution; it could be done through the `layout none` solution which can be found in Isotope extra options and then adding my original Masonry code (bottom of the JS section of the pen link above).

The problem is that when I filter the data, it seems that `display:none` is not added to my actual `.box` div when Masonry is initialized, so reorganization of the layout w/ the filtered data is not happening. Do you have any ideas how could I solve it? Maybe to combine or put my Masonry code into the isotope layout option? but then this snippet was not working for me:

```
columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {return containerWidth / 4;}
```

Other sources I used will be delivered through the comments section if asked.

+1 interesting thing: // layout mode that does not position items

```
Isotope.LayoutMode.create('none');
```

if I change `none` to `masonry` the animation does not start to roll out again, just filters the data nicely (however, the reorganization still does not work)

Comment: Links which might help to understand how I made this code:

http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/mCdbD
http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/AEslp

Comment: Why would you want to do this when isotope has a masonry layout and already has filtering and sorting built in and search is easy to integrate with it as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely right, Isotope is the solution since it has already built-in the masonry layout. Thanks guys!